# Stream array in reverse order / Java

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, reverse

### Reversing an ordered stream

Does **streaming an array** and **then reversing the order of the stream** result in the **overhead** (e.g. like the necessity to fully stream the array first and then iterate on it backwards)**?**

### Using a helper structure

```
final Object[] arr; // assume this is filled
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
Collections.reverse(list);
list.stream();
```

Is the only way to circumvent overhead (e.g. like the creation of an additional List) to iterate over the array in reverse order?

Answer (score 3):

> Does streaming an array and then reversing the order of the stream result in the overhead

Yes.

> Is the only way to circumvent overhead (e.g. like the creation of an additional List) to iterate over the array in reverse order?

Yes, do it with an `IntStream`:

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length).mapToObj(i -> arr[arr.length-1-i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 21 adds the [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) method to `List` which is a view on the original list in reversed order, so you could use that in conjunction with [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) (which creates a `List` view of the array):

```java
final Object[] arr; // assume this is filled
Stream<Object> stream = Arrays.asList(arr).reversed().stream();
```